# Less elements than array size C++

Tags: c++, arrays

How do you handle less elements inputed into an array than its size?
Program won't progress if there are less elements than array size. Is there a way to accept less elements?

```
const int SIZE = 10;
int arr[SIZE] = {};

cout << "Size of the array is " << SIZE << "\n";
cout << "Input values (Separate values by space): ";

for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);   //Scan values separated by space
}
```

Comment: The loop is not infinite. It will complete once `SIZE` items have been entered by the user. Your code does not allow for entering fewer items.

Comment: If you're using C++, you should probably use a `std::vector` and not an array. If you really need to use an array, I will note that this does *not* enter an infinite loop, it just waits for more input. Run your code, and then enter 8 space-separated values and hit enter. Now enter another value and hit enter. Then enter one more value and hit enter again. What happens?

Comment: I see it wasn't an infinite loop. I edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: Don't just blindly read input from the user. They are a cowardly, superstitious lot, and some of them are just plain <expletive deleted>holes. Someone will type in *banana* if for no better reason than to find out what your program does about it. When the answer is "It does nothing!" you're opening yourself up to all sorts of abuses.

Answer (score 1):

This won't be an infinite loop (the `for` is dependent on `SIZE`; it always runs `SIZE` times).

That said, you should check the return value from `scanf`. It returns the number of values successfully parsed; if it's less than or equal to `0`, you ran out of parsable `int`s (additional discrimination on the return value and `errno` can tell you why it stopped parsing additional `int`s). If you stop receiving `int`s, you can set the *real* usable length of the array in a new variable based on the current value of `i`, and never try to use the uninitialized values beyond the values you actually received.

I'll also note that you're using C++, and as such, you'd probably be better off just reading into a `std::vector<int>` which will resize as needed removing the need to explicitly size your storage. You could just read in the data with:

```
const int SIZE = 10;

cout << "Input values (Separate values by space): ";

// If you just want to slurp all values
std::vector<int> arr(std::istream_iterator<int>(cin), std::istream_iterator<int>());

// If you want to slurp a fixed number of values
std::vector<int> arr;
for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
    int tmp;
    if (!(cin >> tmp)) {
        break;
    }
    arr.push_back(tmp);
}
// arr.size() will tell you how many items you actually read
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to accept less elements?

Yes. If there is no input `std::scanf` will return `EOF`. Hence, you could write the loop condition like this:

```
for(int i = 0;
    i < SIZE && std::scanf("%d", &arr[i]) != EOF;
    i++)
```

Sidenote: An array always has constant number of elements. In this case, there are 10 elements regardless of how many of them you assign in the loop. You could use a data structure such as `std::vector` to have exactly as many elements as are inputted.

SIdente 2: I recommend against using `std::scanf`. It's much easier to not make mistakes with the iostream API.

Sidenote 3: Consider whether (and if yes, then how) you need to handle invalid input.

Answer (score 0):

In this case use an object of the type `std::string` and the function `std::getline` to read the whole string of numbers. Then extract numbers from the string for example by using `std::istringstream` or `std::stoi`.

Something like

```
    const size_t SIZE = 10;
    int arr[SIZE] = {};

    std::string input;
    size_t n = 0;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Size of the array is " << SIZE << "\n";
        std::cout << "Input values (Separate values by space): ";

        std::getline( std::cin, input );

        std::istringstream iss( input );
        n = std::distance( std::istream_iterator<int>( iss ),
                           std::istream_iterator<int>() );

        if ( SIZE < n )
        {
            std::cout << "Too many values. Repeat input.\n";
        }                            
    } while ( n <= SIZE );                            

    std::istringstream iss( input );

    std::copy( std::istream_iterator<int>( iss ),
               std::istream_iterator<int>(),
               std::begin( arr ) );
```